# Problem with XCode 4 and xcodebuild: cannot find the UninstalledProducts directory

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

After upgrading to XCode 4 our CI build scripts are not longer working properly. Part of our build process is to archive each app after it's built. To do this the script looks for the built app under the UninstalledProducts directory.  However, with XCode 4 it seems that this directory is no longer created.  Is this new, correct behavior with XCode4?

I just inherited the job of maintaining our iOS CI builds so xcodebuild is new to me.  I have not touched the existing makefile we use for this particular CI build except to changed the value for the target sdk from 'iphoneos4.2' to 'iphoneos4.3'.

Below are the relevant lines from the makefile.  The build fails on the last line because the directory UninstalledProducts can't be found.

```
$(XCODEBUILD) -sdk ${TARGETSDK} -target TheMobileApp -configuration EnterpriseDistribution clean install OTHER_CFLAGS='-DDEBUG=0 -DWEB_COM_URL=@\"https://uat.web.com/the-mobile-app\"'
mv build/UninstalledProducts/TheMobileApp.app ${distdir}/EnterpriseUAT
```

Here's the error message:

```
mv: rename build/UninstalledProducts/TheMobileApp.app to IPHONE_PROJ-r1234/EnterpriseUAT/TheMobileApp.app: No such file or directory
make: *** [compile] Error 1
```

However, it appears that the app is also built at build/EnterpriseDistribution-iphoneos/TheMobileApp.app which is a symlink to /tmp/TheMobileApp.dst/Applications/TheMobileApp.app.  Is this the same app that is built under UninstalledProducts?

Any help much appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about trying `$OBJROOT/UninstalledProducts`?

Answer (score 3):

Add this parameter to the xcodebuild command:

```
SKIP_INSTALL=YES
```

See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html for reference.